# jbpm6 the actors of user task

Tags: actor, jbpm

I make new jBPM Process with "a more advanced process including human tasks and persistence". Then run the process ,everything is fine. But if I change the actor of user task,for example, I change “mary” to “may” on Task 2

,a error will happen,the list’s size is 0.

```
    // let john execute Task 1
    List<TaskSummary> list = taskService.getTasksAssignedAsPotentialOwner("john", "en-UK");
    TaskSummary task = list.get(0);
    System.out.println("John is executing task " + task.getName());
    taskService.start(task.getId(), "john");
    taskService.complete(task.getId(), "john", null);

    assertNodeTriggered(processInstance.getId(), "Task 2");

    // let mary execute Task 2
    list = taskService.getTasksAssignedAsPotentialOwner("may", "en-UK");
    System.out.println("list.size:"+list.size());
    task = list.get(0);
    System.out.println("May is executing task " + task.getName());
    taskService.start(task.getId(), "may");
    taskService.complete(task.getId(), "may", null);
```

then a error will happen,the console shows that the list's size is 0.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Cause this are the users in userinfo.properties
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-human-task/jbpm-human-task-core/src/test/resources/userinfo.properties

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behaviour.. if your processes create tasks for Mary but you query the tasks for May, it will return 0 tasks for May. Then the rest of the lines will fail.

Comment: I have changed the task for may,and it doesn't work.

Comment: @salaboy how do you actually create tasks for a specific user? Is it through the actor id?

Comment: yeah, you set the actorId in the process designer. That's available when you define a user task in a process. If you want the process automatically assigned you just need to add one potentialOwner/actorId

Comment: So it means that we cannot use our own existing organisation schema while using jbpm except for ldap. But what about other options like custom  web application organisation like users

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the new user 'may' to UserGroupCallback?